# Having an integer inside a method that increases by 1 everytime the method was called to a specific object of a lass

Tags: c#, arrays, class, methods

I have a 'Movie' class in my C# code that has an `int[] ratings = new int[10];` as a field. I would like to place numbers in this empty array from my main program.

For that, I would need a method, that could point to the actual free index of the array to put the integer there, but the other integer that would point to the free index would be reset to 0 everytime the method is called. Thus, my question is, that how can I place an integer in my method that is increased everytime the method was called.

This is the method in the class:

```
public void Rate(int rating)
{
   int x = 0;
   ratings[x] = rating;   

}
```

This is how I call it in the main program

```
Movie asd = new Movie(blabla...);
Rate.asd(1);
Rate.asd(1);
Rate.asd(1);
```

So I called it 3 times, and I would want the 'x' integer in the class's method to increase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste code to show what you've tried.

Comment: Well you need to store the integer somewhere alongside the array, it cannot last in the method.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. You have posted half baked code that you yourself said does not work and we are to psychically debug your code without knowing what its meant to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have an error in the code you have posted.
As I suppose rather than:

```
Movie asd = new Movie(blabla...);
Rate.asd(1);
Rate.asd(1);
Rate.asd(1);
```

you want to paste here:

```
Movie asd = new Movie(blabla...);
asd.Rate(1);
asd.Rate(1);
asd.Rate(1);
```

As C# does not allow to use static method variables (like i.e. C++ does) you have two options:

- first, make x value (from Rate method) a Movie's class variable, so Rate method will "remember" the next index,
- second (and better) rather than intiger array - if possible use any kind of list or queue (which can manage indexing for you).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that local variables are discarded when exiting a method.

```
class SomeClass
{
    private int x = 42;

    public void DoSometing(int y)
    {
        int a = y + 5;
        x += a * a;
        // a stops to exist here
    }
}
```

Solution is to store the variable in the containing class as well

```
class SomeOtherClass
{
    private int x = 42;
    private int a = 0;

    public void DoSomething(int y)
    {
        a = y + 5;
        x += a * a;
    }
}
```

Now `SomeOtherClass` remembers the value of `a`. That's basically the point of member variables a.k.a. fields - to store the state of the object.

More appropriate for your problem:

```
class ClassWithAnArrayAndCount
{
    private int[] values = new int[10];
    private int   taken  = 0;

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        if (taken == 10)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); // sorry, no more space

        values[taken++] = value;
    }

    public int Taken { get { return taken; } }
}
```